# The following code is supposed to read a file and print the file contents to the Terminal window. It doesn’t work, I'm not sure why?

Tags: python

The following code is supposed to read a file and print the file contents to the Terminal window. It doesn’t work, I'm not sure why?

```
filename = raw_input(’Provide the path to a text file: ’)
txt = open(filename)
print txt
```

Comment: have you considered reading the documentation for files in Python?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The built-in `open` function returns a `file` object, not the contents of that file. For that you would have to call the `read()` or `readlines()` method of that file object for example, depending on how you want your output. Also, take care to call `close()` after opening a file, or to open it using a `with` statement to do so automatically for you ([reference](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/)).

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to use straight quotes `'` instead of smart quotes `’`. Second, you need to actually read the opened file with something like `read()`.

```
filename = raw_input('Provide the path to a text file: ')
txt = open(filename).read()
print txt
```